# Set the value of a variable in django template using 'with' tag for checking in an 'if' condition. But get's error : 'endif', expected 'endwith'

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have set a variable as False in django templates, then sets the variable to True in an if condition both using 'with var=True/False' I use seperate 'endwith' tags for each 'with' tag.
But I'm getting an error saying 'endif', expected 'endwith'.

Template code as below:

```
{% date_range as the_days %}

{% for day in the_days %}
  {% with is_order_day=False %}

    {% for order in orders %
        {% if order.created_at.date == day.date in orders %}
            {% with is_order_day=True %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if is_order_day %}
        <p>{{day.date}}</p>
    {% endif %}

{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss the closing template syntax on the line `{% for order in orders %`

Comment: yeah got that one, closed it {% for order in orders %} but still gets the same error

Comment: Wouldn't it be like 100x easier to do the logic in the backend and just send the variable `is_order_day` to the template? I honestly don't feel like spinning up a Django project to test this out to see what the problem is to try and solve it.

Comment: Yeah I finally resorted to django custom template tags (simple tags) andseperated the logic into python, yeah I think it is the right way.